# Hat gets misplaced both in icon and on profile picture (2021 Winter Bash)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, winter-bash

I think that if the hats get resized that the position of the hat gets re-calculated incorrectly, probably from (X,Y) position that is shifted according to the hat. Simply wearing the hat and returning to the hat-"dialog" screen will already move the position of the hat.

[image]
[image]

Also seen on the icon, which triggered my small exploration:

[image]

I think it is hat size related as it seems to move in the other direction if the hat is smaller.

Using Firefox 95.0 on Ubuntu, mostly mint condition (but includes an add blocker, if that's important). I've included the pictures taken from the [Cryptography site](https://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's different depending on the site's image, and all my images are 1:1 ratio to avoid the *ratio bug*; so this won't be a simple fix. Just got through adjusting a few dozen hat positions because I have custom avatars on quite a few sites.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This one was hard to find, but we believe we have a fix!

The short story here is: we were calculating the positioning of the hat inside the hat adjustment modal a little too soon, which meant that the hat would render on a different position there. As soon as someone tried to adjust it inside that modal, it would break the real thing.

The hat should now only be rendered when the modal is fully loaded, which should fix the issue going forward.

You should also now be able to go into the hat adjustment modal and fix the positioning of your hat.

Let us know if for some reason it doesn't work for you!

Thanks for reporting! We appreciate the help.

Comment: I have to give public kudos to Felippe on this one - this was a crazy bug to crack (and was his first work on anything touching the front-end of WB, which is…quite complex), especially because it seemingly happened at random in a very hard-to-understand section of UI logic. Thanks!